# Running iOS app on the simulator using Jenkins

Tags: ios, command-line, jenkins, simulator, nsrunningapplication

I'm setting up my CI server with Jenkins. I can successfully build the app but now I need a way to run it in the simulator. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out WaxSim? It's a command-line app to run the simulator. I've heard various noises about it not working on Mac OSX 10.8 but they may have fixed this now.

https://github.com/square/waxsim

Comment: I've just found this.It's called ios-sim https://github.com/downloads/pegli/ios-sim/ios-sim-xcode4.3.tar.gz
It runs smoothly but the app goes in backgrounds after launching. I need it in foreground to start my UI test

Comment: btw waxsim is giving this error:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
  Referenced from: /Users/MyMac/Desktop/./waxsim
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Answer (score 0):

ios-sim (https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) works fine. Just be sure to build the debug version of the app otherwise it will go in background after the being deployed.